# Asterisk / Trixbox Allow Inbound Caller to redial and bridge

Tags: asterisk, trixbox, freepbx

I want a caller to be able to phone into asterisk from a mobile phone or a pay phone and then enter a special PIN and allow them to dial another number.

This could allow for significant savings on long distance calls.

Is there a build in module or functionality for doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is called DISA and is built into Asterisk. Here is a [walkthrough](http://www.asteriskguru.com/tutorials/disa.html). If you have FreePBX, you can do this through the GUI...look on the left side under "Internal Options and Configurations."